# Free meal with probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am new to probability theory! There’s restaurant named ’Treat’. In this after every meal, the manager picks one from
each of the five well shuffled pack of cards having cards labeled A-T. If the picked cards form the
restaurant’s name (in any order) the meal is on the house.

What is the probability that a person will enjoy a free meal?

The manager wants to change the structure of game so that the probability of winning would be
less for an expensive meal while it will be more for a cheaper meal. Suggest a way to change the
’winning word’ (according to charge of meal), to satisfy manager’s needs

Comment: Could you edit into your question what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: "Why every mf is commenting instead of solving problem? Useless platform"  Don't be rude!  *No-one* is entitled to answers and *every* post and suggestion is given freely and voluntarily and there is no reason anyone should take any of them for granted.  Be a little gracious.

Comment: "The manager wants to change the structure of game so that the probability of winning would be less for an expensive meal while it will be more for a cheaper meal. Suggest a way to change the ’winning word’ (according to charge of meal), to satisfy manager’s needs" well, thats vague and open-ended enough to be an utterly worthless question.  And considering you are more likely to die of 15 cats falling on you from a hot air balloon then you are of winning a free meal, rather petty of the cook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent, Content, and math are not magic.  There is no magic answer to a question regardless as to *how* the question is interpretted.  So if a question is unclear in meaning it can have *different* valid answer based one which interpretation.

I was unclear how many of each letter each pack of cards and were the cards shuffled and does the chef pick randomly.

FWIW, I think the must reasonable interpretation is that each pack contains $20$ cards with $1$ card for each letter from $A$ to $T$ and cards are picked on from each stack.

To get a free meal, we must pick two $T$s, an $E$, an $A$, and an $R$; one from each pack.

If we use that interpretation the answer is straightforward.

> If order mattered, to draw a $T$ from pack $1$, $R$ from pack $2$, etc, the probability would be $(\frac 1{20})^5$.  As order doesn't matter we must figure the number of ways to order then the letters $T,R,E,A,T$ and as each is equally likely multiply that number by $(\frac 1{20})^5$.  There are ${5\choose 2}$ ways to place the $T$ and of the remaining three letters and remaining three positions there are $3!$ ways to place the $E,A,R$.  So the probability is $3!{5\choose 2}\frac 1{20^5}=6\frac {4*5}2\frac 1{20^5}= \frac {60}{20^5} = \frac 3{20^{19}}$. .... In other words, fat chance..... Nasty, selfish, promotion in my opinion.  Those probabilities are more appropriate for the chances of being hit by a falling space station at 3:17 on a Friday while visiting the Anne Frank Museum in Amsterdam than for getting an mudder-frogging free meal.  Sheesh, who writes these questions.